# CLAPACK not linking

Tags: lapack

I have downloaded CLAPACK and built it according to these instructions:

http://www.netlib.org/clapack/readme.install

Everything was OK and I had no errors.  I then put my three headers blaswrap.h clapack.h and f2c.h into the /usr/local/include folder.

I put the libraries blas_LINUX.a, lapack_LINUX.a and tmglib_LINUX.a into the folder /usr/local/lib64

I then try and link in my C file

```
#include "blaswrap.h"
#include "f2c.h"
#include "clapack.h"
```

When Linking I do this

```
-g -O3  -lm -L/usr/local/lib64
```

I have tried to link to the actual library like

```
-lcblas -llapack
```

And many other ways but still no luck.  Any ideas what I could try?

And I get the error

```
fatal error: blaswrap.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you try something like `-lblas_LINUX -llapack_LINUX` ? Since you named these libraries that way... Another solution would be to add `-I /path/to/clapack.h -L /path/to/liblapack.a` and `libcblas.a`